# Android Tabhost not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to implment a tabhost in Android. I've done eveything correctly in terms of setting it up but when I run the page, I get a null pointer exception which does not display the tabhost control on my android phone and generates the following stack trace:

```
 Radio_Debug [Android Application]  
        DalvikVM[localhost:8604]    
            Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
                TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(boolean) line: 295   
                LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(boolean) line: 664   
                FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(boolean) line: 664    
                LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(boolean) line: 664   
                PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(boolean) line: 664  
                ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1819  
                ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
                Looper.loop() line: 123 
                ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
                Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
                Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
                ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
                ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
                NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
            Thread [<17> Binder Thread #4] (Running)    
            Thread [<15> Binder Thread #3] (Running)    
            Thread [<13> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
            Thread [<11> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

The java code is linked to the xml page code is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class tabs extends Activity{


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabmain);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();


    }



}
```

The xml file layout which houses the tabhost control is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabHost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>

                   <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1">


                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2">


                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3">


                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab4">


                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>




    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any views inside this tabhost?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with 4 text views and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

You never establish any tabs. You need to call `newTabSpec()` and `addTab()` methods on the `TabHost` to set up the tabs, pointing to children of your `TabWidget`. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab) demonstrating this.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Even with the code that I have so far, it should not be generating an error. I've since tried it with the tabs and text views and I'm still getting the same error. Do you know what I might be missing?

Comment: @user615099: "Even with the code that I have so far, it should not be generating an error" -- you will get an error if you have an empty `TabHost`. "Do you know what I might be missing?" -- off the top of my head, no, which is why I pointed you to a sample that works, so you can try to determine what is different between your code and the sample.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are the man :) your little sample helped me figure out what was wrong with my layout in my tabhost.....much thanks :)